# Remove any view from any where e.g from window

Tags: swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer, ibaction

I have 2 views on the screen, one is overlayView at the bottom and introView at the top of that overlayView. When I tap(tapToContinueAction) on the screen they should both hide or remove themselves.

```
extension UIView {
 ....
 func hideView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.isHidden = hidden
    })
}
}
```

---

```
class IntroScreen
 @IBAction func tapToContinueAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.hideView(view: self, hidden: true)
}
```

--

```
class OverlayView : UiView {
  ...
 }
```

In current situation i can hide introScreen only and i dont know how the other class's action can effect the overlayView at the same time and hide that view as well. Any idea?

Comment: both overlay and intro have shared a same parentView?

Comment: yes @SyedQamarAbbas they are on UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

Comment: if you have reference of other view just call hideview function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different classes for your views. Make an extension of your window to remove your specific views just like I have made `removeOverlay` and `removeIntroView` both these computed properties will go and search in subviews list of `window` and check each view with their type and remove them. Thats how you can remove any view form any where.

```
class OverLayView: UIView {}
class IntroView: UIView {
    @IBAction func didTapYourCustomButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
        window.removeOverlay
        window.removeIntroView
    }
}
extension UIWindow {
    var removeOverlay: Void {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview is OverLayView {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()// here you are removing the view.
                subview.hidden = true// you can hide the view using this
            }
        }
    }
    var removeIntroView: Void {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview is IntroView {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()// here you are removing the view.
                subview.hidden = true// you can hide the view using this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as charm! Thanks a lot!